# JQuery Autocomplete INLINE (like firebug)

Tags: jquery, firebug, inline

I'm aware of the JQuery Autocomplete plugins but those provide answers to you in a dropdown list below the typed text. Is there a method or a plugin that allows you to have the autocomplete feature simliar to Firebug (when typing in CSS) or Google Developer Tools where the answers are provided to the user inline with the text they are typing?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Plugin [`inlineComplete()`](http://pburke.de/jquery-inlinecomplete-inline-auto-complete-for-text-input/) should satisfy your requirements:

http://pburke.de/jquery-inlinecomplete-inline-auto-complete-for-text-input/

```
var termListUrls = ["facebook.com", "apple.de", "google.de", "www.golem.de", "golem.de"];

$('[name=autocomplete_urls]').inlineComplete({
    submitOnReturn: true,
    terms: termListUrls
});
```

***Live Demo**: http://pburke.de/jquery/inlinecomplete/*

Comment: This did not work for me.  The demo page on the site is broken (as is the demo link in this answer above), and when I downloaded it, the demo page in the included files was broken as well.  I tried to look into the code but could not fix it.

Answer (score 0):

After a while looking for a autocomplete inline with ajax(database access), i decided to write one. Hope the result can be helpful http://plugins.jquery.com/tryonline/